# In C# unity from optimization point of view should we multiply a data type with numbers directly or every number should be stored in variables

Tags: c#, optimization, memory-management

Is it important to store all the values in variables that we are going to use for mathematical calculations? Or its okay if I multiply a result / variable directly with float number specially when its going to be executed every frame.

For example I have to apply a calculated force to my player. Which is the best optimized way from following 2 methods, and how?

Code 1 : Multiply directly

```
Rigidbody Player;

void Update()
{
    Player.AddForce(Vector3.forward * 2.5f * 4.5f * 2);
}
```

or

```
Code 2 : Store values in variables and then use

float speed = 2.5f;
float speed_multiplier = 4.5f;
float additional_force = 2;
float resultant_force;
Rigidbody Player;

void Update()
{
    resultant_force = speed * force_multiplier * additional_force;
    Player.AddForce(Vector3.forward * resultant_force);
}
```

Which one calculates faster without caching extra memory. Which is better from CPU calculations and memory optimization point of view?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR;** The difference will be minimal either way.

---

`* 2.5f * 4.5f * 2` would definitely be completely inlined by the JIT or Native Compiler (AOT).

On the other hand, keeping them in variables is better for encapsulation and avoiding magic numbers. It *may* be slightly slower, it may not, but you are really only talking about a couple clock cycles.

It depends how heavily the compiler optimizes.  I suspect it would probably not be optimized if they are fields, whereas local variables would be inlined.

**Get the best of both worlds by using constants, these will be inlined exactly like your first option.**

```cs
const float speed = 2.5f;
const float speed_multiplier = 4.5f;
const float additional_force = 2;
```

Incidentally, `float resultant_force;` is useless anyway and can be removed or made into a local variable.

Comment: As you said fields won't be optimized. Can you clarify on this situation
- I am targeting mainly for Android games on med end devices
- Most of the variables will be public so either they will be assigned at runtime or via another object.
- There are very less variables that can have actually constant values throughout the game session.

Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: I very much doubt it makes any noticeable difference unless you are running it in an extremely tight loop. But if you need those public properties/fields you have no other choice. A basic auto-property would have it's getter inlined to a field access.